# React.js: Set Prop only when condition is true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm quite new to react.js and have some troubles passing props to children. 
I want to do something like this:

```
render: function(){
   var idProp = this.props.id ? 'id={this.props.id}' : null;
   return (
     <div {idProp} />
   );
}
```

So the prop id should only be passed if a condition is true.
But the above code is not working. 
Is this possible? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? There is no harm in passing a null prop to your child.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`var idProp = this.props.id ? 'id={this.props.id}' : null;` in your code should be written in javascript way. Also you have to move "id=" to the JSX syntax.

```
render: function(){
   var idProp = this.props.id ? this.props.id : null;
   return (
     <div id={idProp} />
   );
}
```

The JSX compiler converts the code to pure js first. To create dom elements, it uses the `React.createElement(...)` function. To identify the parameters for the function, the JSX compiler needs attribute names of the element to be static. The converted javascript of the above code will be..

```
render: function(){
   var idProp = this.props.id ? this.props.id : null;
   return (
     React.createElement("div", {id: idProp})
   );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this neatly with the spread operator if you can use it.

```
render: function() {
    var optionalProps = {};
    if (something) optionalProps.id = id;
    return (<div {...optionalProps} />);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With this approach, you don't have to declare an empty object, is possible to validate inline within the component JSX tag.

```
<Component  {...(id && {id})} />
```