# Send a prop only if condition is true in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React.js in some project and I wanted to send a prop only if a condition is true, **what I don't want is** to send null values or empty stuff as the following example (or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26951617/react-js-set-prop-only-when-condition-is-true)):

```
return (
    <SomeComponent
        prop1={foo === true ? "value" : null}
    />
);
```

I want to send the whole prop (not only its value) if a condition is true, something like this:

```
render: function(){

    ...

    return (
        <SomeComponent
           {if(foo === true) prop1="value"}
        />
    );
}
```

I also tried

```
    ...

    var prop1;
    if(foo === true) prop1 = "prop1='value'";

    return <SomeComponent {prop1} />;
```

and of course something like

```
    ...

    return (
        </SomeComponent
            {foo === true ? prop1="value" : ""}
        />
    );
```

In all cases I got a `Unexpected token` error, I have been searching but I haven't found anything, is there any way to do that in react?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you care if you pass a property with undefined value?

Comment: Agreed, what's the actual purpose? The component will still have to know if the prop was passed in order to handle both cases. So far this seems like an XY problem-can you explain the use case?

Comment: Basically I was curious if you can do that in react and I thought the code would look cleaner that way, at least using  @OmriAharon solution, even having in mind that the component will have to check for both cases anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though not sure what's the purpose - with ES6 spread operator, you can do it like this:

```
const props = {};

if (foo === true) { // or just if (foo) {
   props.prop1 = 'value';
}

<SomeComponent
   { ...props } />
```

Comment: You should add what @DaveNewton said in the comments ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685032/send-a-prop-only-if-condition-is-true-in-react-js/38685195#comment64749378_38685032)) to make this answer even more useful

Answer (score 1):

> Well even if you send the undefined values, you will always have the
>   chance to validate in either of the two functions: **componentWillMount**
>   for the first load or **componentWillReceiveProps** after first load.
>   Besides you can always have the **render** function to validate. But if I
>   answer as per the approach you are trying.

```
render : function(){
if(foo === true)
    return <SomeComponent prop1 ="value1" />;
else
     return <SomeComponent />;
}
```

> And in the rendered component you can use the **getDefaultProps** function
>   to set the default values if you doesn't pass any prop values which is
>   your second case.